# Gnuplot script bash problem

Tags: command-line, bash, syntax, gnuplot

I have wrote this script in bash

```
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing file... $f"
  # take action on each file. $f store current file name
  B=$(basename $f)
  filename="${B%.*}"
  mkdir $BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename
  ./../graphic_file_gen $f > $BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/data.txt
  cd $BASEDIR/$RESULTS/$filename/
  gnuplot << EOF 
  do for [i=0:33] { number = i-2 set term png set output "fotorivelatore".number.".png" unset key set title "Fotorivelatore ".number plot [:16384] [:40000] 'data.txt' using 0:i with linespoints } EOF
  #./../test2 $f 
  cd $BASEDIR/$DECADIMENTI/
done
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus is at the end of the line that starts with "do for"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `EOF` in a new line

See [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Comment: this does not solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: @user5355783 it needs to be on a new line and at the beginning of the line. If you have changed your script and it still doesn't work, please edit your question and show us the current version of the script. I just tested here with the `EOF` ona  new line and it worked fine. \